# ISPConfig showing default apache page

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, php

I am trying to install ISPConfig on Debian Jessie.
I was following this tut https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/3/

I can install everything alright, but when I access https://ip:8080/ I get the default apache page. Why is this happening?

In my /var/www/ folder there is an html/ folder, as well as an ispconfig/ folder, and I tried moving ispconfig into html but when I try to access it the php is not run.
And no, short tags are not the problem.

I tried a2dissite 000-default and then service apache2 restart but all stays the same.

Maybe I have to make some configuration that enables me to run different websites on different ports? In /etc/apache2/sites-available/ there is:

- 000-default.conf
- apps.vhost
- default-ssl.conf ispconfig.conf
- ispconfig.vhost

I am not really sure what to do. I don't have much experience with apache

**What are you trying to do?**

I am trying to get ISPConfig to run when I access https://ip:8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Basics**

It seems like a virtual host entry would possibly solve this issue.

Under the following directory:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

copy & rename *000-default.conf*, keeping the .*conf* extension e.g.

```
 # cp 000-default.conf virtual.isp3.conf .
```

Edit your new .conf file and make it look something like this (note particularly the :8080):

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

ServerName example.tld
ServerAlias www.example.tld *.example.tld
DocumentRoot /path/to/isp3/

</VirtualHost>
```

This should set all requests to that server on port 8080 to pull from /path/to/isp3/

Note that you don't have to delete any lines, just uncomment them.

Once edited, save the .conf and enable it with a2ensite e.g.

```
# a2ensite virtual.isp3.conf
```

Then restart Apache

```
# service apache2 restart
```

---

**Caveats**

- If ISP3 is still failing, try a regular html page first to test the virtual host configuration (i.e. set DocumentRoot to access this custom plain page).
- You may need to add or configure addition options for SSL access.
- Likewise, if the plain page works, but a .php based page doesn't, you may need to take additional steps to make sure the server can parse .php files.

Comment: I was a bit confused before as to what I was supposed to do exactly but I have now figured out. I just want the ispconfig folder to run under /var/www/html, but the php is not working. I have already commented out the lines I was supposed to comment, but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, ispconfig url was showing apache default page, it was fixed by:

```
yum install mod_fcgid
service httpd restart
```